# go how to write append file by using ioutil

Tags: go

I try to use the following code

```
appendStr := []byte("append test")
ioutil.WriteFile("./test.txt", appendStr, os.ModeAppend)
```

but it seems does not work

Comment: What happens when you run the above code? Does it overwrite the file, or result in an error, or something else?

Comment: You have to open a file in append mode to automatically append to it. This is not something `ioutil` alone (a package which is no longer needed, all functionality is handled by `io` or `os`) can do

Comment: The documentation seems clear: *If the file does not
    exist, WriteFile creates it ... otherwise
    WriteFile truncates it before writing...*  The `perm` argument is only used to set permissions on a newly created file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JimB already explained

```
appendStr := []byte("\n append test")
f, err := os.OpenFile("text.log", os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()
n, err := f.Write(appendStr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n)
```